# How to change the style of HTML list items using setInterval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML code with 3 list items and the ids for my ul is 'exercise6-list'

```
<ul id="exercise6-list">

<li>List 1</li>

<li>List 2</li>

<li>List 3</li>

</ul>
```

I need to make each li glow for three seconds and repeat itself

So far I have written:

```
var moveGlow = function() {

 var element = document.querySelector("#exercise6-list");

 // ... to make it glow i've so far used .setAttribute("class", "glow")

};

clearInterval(window.interval);
window.interval = setInterval(moveGlow, 3000);
```

*I'm very new to programming, but thank you for your help

Comment: What exactly would you be looping over?

Comment: Probably each li, i.e. the children of the ul.

Comment: @Theresa, have you tried what you are proposing? I'd start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a timed function we use `setInterval`, and add the class "glow" to the current element, and remove that class from the previous one.
To cycle through the elements, we use an index-variable, which increases per cycle and loops back around when necessary.

```js
let index = 0;
let elements = document.querySelector("#exercise6-list").children;
let glowFunc = () => {
  if (elements.length <= 0) { // Actually not needed since we know there are 3 elements
    index = 0;
    return;
  }
  index %= elements.length; // Map index to valid values
  elements[(elements.length + index - 1) % elements.length].classList.remove("glow"); // Remove "glow" from previous element
  elements[index].classList.add("glow"); // Add "glow" to current element
  ++index; // Increase 'index'
};

glowFunc(); // Initial call to "start" it without initial delay
setInterval(glowFunc, 3000); // Make it a timed function
```

```css
li {transition: background-color 0.2s}
.glow {background-color: orange}
```

```html
<ul id="exercise6-list">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setInterval I used setTimeout since interval keeps running until you stop it, where as timeout only happens once then you have to rerun it.

This code is a recursive function that uses a counter to determine where in the list the loop is currently at.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector("#exercise6-list");
var children = parent.querySelectorAll("li");
var total = children.length;

function glow(counter) {

  children.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("highlight");
  });

  el = children[counter];

  el.classList.add("highlight");
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (counter < total - 1) {
      counter++;
      glow(counter);
    }
    else{
     el.classList.remove("highlight");
    }
  }, 3000);
}

glow(0);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<ul id="exercise6-list">
  <li>111</li>
  <li>222</li>
  <li>333</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're going recursive, the `counter` seems like state only the function should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.from(element.children).forEach(child => {
  child.classList.add('glow');
  
  setTimeout(() => child.classList.remove('class'), 3000);
});
```

However, I *think* weird things will happen if you make each `li` glow for longer than the interval, which you have currently set to 300.

If you use something like jQuery you don't need to iterate manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an recursive solution with async await.

```js
var moveGlow = async function() {
 var element = document.querySelector(".box");
 element.style.background = "green";
 await sleep(3000)
 element.style.background = "red"
 await sleep(3000);
 return moveGlow()
}

let sleep = (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time))

moveGlow()
```

```css
.box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d=document.querySelector("#exercise6-list");
d.style="background-color:yellow;"
setTimeout(()=>{
  d.style=""
},3000)
//time is measured in milliseconds.. simple math
```

```html
<div style="background-color:yellow" id="exercise6-list">
<li>Text 1</li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
</div>
```